# Is it okay that a Muslim be fan of a church soccer team?

Tags: punishment

I 'm Muslim and I support one of church soccer teams.does it have any problem for Muslims to support another religion team?and will I go to hell because of that?

Comment: Please elaborate the question. And welcome to [islam.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assalam Alaikum,

May Allah (SWT) bestows upon you His Blessings.

You question can bear many different meanings to the word **Support**. I will talk generally trying to cover all the aspects.

There is nothing wrong in supporting a soccer team. As long as supporting them does not in any way affect your actions to be immoral, all is well. There is a lot said in Quran relating to the treatments of non-muslims, even our beloved Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) has stated at plenty of places as to how a non-muslim should be treated.

One of the hadith the Prophet (Peace be upon him) is more explicit, he said:

> If any Muslim killed a Muahid (i.e. non-Muslim living in Muslim land with agreement) then he (muslim) shall not even smell the fragrance of Paradise although the fragrance of Paradise would have been perceived from the distance of travelling for 40 years [Sahih Bukhari, Volume No. 3, Hadith # 2995]

Being a muslim, does not mean that you restrict yourself to only muslims, if that was the case, Islam would not have been the fastest growing religion in the world but more of a small closed community consisting of only those who were born in that religion.

So bear in mind, as long as supporting a soccer team means, that you watch them play, physically and financially help them in a way that you know your finances are put to good use and a good cause, it is fine. In case of any doubt, it is better to be more clear of that certain doubt. I hope this answers your question.

May Allah be pleased with you and all of us, Amen!

Comment: I hope my answer helped you in some way, if you think you're happy with the answer, please do accept it ... Thanks :) 
Assalam Alaikum